# VSCODE: how to run python without this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just start to use vscode. I want to write a Python script with it. When I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, it looks like this..
[image]
How to skip this control？
The only extention I use is `donjayamanne.python`

Comment: That is the debugger interface. You *cannot* skip it.

Answer (score 1):

The Debug Actions pane that pops up allows you to control the debugging.
I think your issue is that the `donjayamanne.python` extension by default pauses execution on the first line, requiring you to press play, or <kbd>F5</kbd> a second time.

To change this behaviour, you need to modify `launch.json` and change the line `"stopOnEntry": true,` to `"stopOnEntry": false,`